# Can we use a variable defined in one php file, in another php file

Tags: php

I have defined a variable $month is "water_sources.php" file. Can I use this variable in another file "add_month.php" If yes then please suggest how?

Comment: `include 'water_sources.php';`

Comment: @Rocket: include can actually fail and the script will continue executing (albeit with a warning).

Comment: @Chris: True, use `require` instead.  `require` will stop the script on an error, `include` won't.

Comment: I tried using "include" before but by that all the statements that I am printing using "echo" in "water_source.php" file are getting printed in "month.php" file also which is not required.. Is there any other option by which I can use this variable "$month" from "water_sources.php" without printing all the statements again?

Comment: Both include and require will pull in "water_sources.php" and execute it line by line. A variable isn't available until it's been evaluated, and the only way that can happen is that the php file is executed. So no you can't do that (easily).

Comment: Also, you don't need to put the same message up in multiple places.

Answer (score 9):

Simple answer is yes.  Take a look at the docs for `include`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php, `require`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php, and `require_once`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php.  Which you use will depend on whether the file is... you guessed it, required.  :)

Luckily, the mechanics for using each are identical.  In the sample code below, you could interchange `require` or `require_once` for `include` and the demo will still function correctly.  Try to create the files and use each of the functions.  Then, delete the `vars.php` file and try your tests again.  Notice that your script will fail if you use `require` and the included file does not exist.

**vars.php**

```
<?php

$color = 'green'; $fruit = 'apple';

?>
```

**test.php**

```
<?php

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A

include 'vars.php';

echo "A $color $fruit"; // A green apple

?>
```

Comment: I tried using "include" before but by that all the statements that I am printing using "echo" in "water_source.php" file are getting printed in "month.php" file also which is not required.. Is there any other option by which I can use this variable "$month" from "water_sources.php" without printing all the statements again?

Comment: Huh?  Why don't you post the source code from both files in your question so we can see exactly what you're working with.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can. Just use the `require` or `require_once` commands to pull in the other php file. Like this:

```
require_once('water_sources.php');
echo "Month is $month\n";
```

Comment: I tried using "include" before but by that all the statements that I am printing using "echo" in "water_source.php" file are getting printed in "month.php" file also which is not required.. Is there any other option by which I can use this variable "$month" from "water_sources.php" without printing all the statements again?

Answer (score 1):

If you include the file "water_sources.php" then you can reference the variables. See the reference on "scope" ( http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php )

Answer (score 1):

simply convert the variable into session variable which you want to use in another php file .

For example, if i have created login page in which I define username as a variable which will be same throughout the session .
so I'll write here

```
$_SESSION['username']=$username;
```

and use in another php file like you want to echo out that variable then use

```
echo '$_SESSION['username']';
```